# Outlook Email Client Background Image Not Working (using background.cm solution)

Tags: html, email, outlook

I'm trying to add this background image the my html email signature, i've tried background.cm tactic but nothing seems to work...

the idea behind this is to use the image as a layout in he signature and place the data on top of it so the text is selectable and all the graphic part of the signature is just a background image.

I've tried this so far:

```
<body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background-color: #ffffff;" bgcolor="#ffffff">
    <div style="background-color:#7bceeb;">
        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
        <v:background xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="t">
            <v:fill type="tile" src="https://i.ibb.co/Df6qZ2R/back.png" color="#7bceeb"/>
        </v:background>
        <![endif]-->
        <table width="590" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" align="left" background="https://i.ibb.co/Df6qZ2R/back.png">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <table width="305" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td height="110" valign="bottom" align="center">
                                            <a href="#"><span><img src="instagram.png" width="20"></span></a>
                                            </span><a href="#"><span><img src="facebook.png" width="20"></a>
                                            <a href="#"><span><img src="tiktok.png" width="20"></span></a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <table width="290" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td height="110" valign="bottom" align="center">
                                            <span style="font-size: 20px; line-height: 25px; font-weight: 700;">Ronen
                                            Barashi</span>
                                            <br />
                                            <span style="font-size: 18px; line-height: 25px;">CEO & Co-founder</span>
                                            <br />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="305" height="148">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <table height="145" width="290" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                    <tr height="10"></tr>
                                    <tr style="color: #ffffff;">
                                        <td valign="top" align="right" width="50"><img src="wa-icon.png" width="18">
                                        </td>
                                        <td width="5"></td>
                                        <td valign="top" align="left">95425925482</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr style="color: #ffffff;">
                                        <td valign="top" align="right" width="50"><img src="mail-icon.png" width="19">
                                        </td>
                                        <td width="5"></td>
                                        <td valign="top" align="left">ronen@grandeurauto.co.za</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr style="color: #ffffff;">
                                        <td valign="top" align="right" width="50"><img src="wa-icon.png" width="18">
                                        </td>
                                        <td width="5"></td>
                                        <td valign="top" align="left">www.grandeurauto.co.za</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr style="color: #ffffff;">
                                        <td valign="top" align="right" width="50"><img src="wa-icon.png" width="18">
                                        </td>
                                        <td width="5"></td>
                                        <td valign="top" align="left">Rivonia crossing 2, 3 Achter road sunninghill
                                            Sandton, Sandton
                                            2191
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

i can see the background image on browser but when i add to outlook it is not there.